# If I remove a remove a subset of a uniform distribution, will it remain uniform?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

suppose that I have a long sequence of random numbers coming from a uniform distribution. If I remove a small subset from the sequence (either part of the sequence, or randomly pick some elements), will the remaining sequence still be a uniform distribution?

Thank you!

edit: all of the elements are generated from the same distribution. For example generate 10,000 values randomly from a uniform distribution with a range of [0,1]

Comment: As you state it, I understand that every variable is uniformly distributed. So, if you remove some of them the others will not be affected. So, yes, they will remain uniform

Comment: All of the numbers come from the same distribution. So I know for sure that if the set is small, then the proposition does not hold. Because if you have 10 numbers and you remove 7, I do not expect the 3 remaining to be uniformly distributed.

Comment: Yes, ok, but what you say now is something else as the initial question.

Comment: Note: We would not say a sequence (or a sample) is uniformly distributed; but rather that items in the sequence (or sample) come from a uniform distribution.

Comment: Sorry about that, my fault.

Comment: If the set is small the proposition does hold. Take a iid sample $X_1,\dots,X_{10}$ from a uniform, and discard the first $8$. We are left with an iid sample from a uniform.

Comment: The crucial issue is how you choose the observations to be removed. If you remove the last few in a random sequence it is just as if you had a smaller sample size. If you randomly select a few to remove that is also OK. But, for example, if you sorted the data and removed a few of the lowest (or highest), then certainly not.